# why Python isn't completing the def statement?

Tags: python, indentation, definition

Still beginning my journey using Python so this is a simple question that I don't understand.

Trying to use Ziggy's definition statement of Cramer's V statistic from here:
[Using pandas, calculate Cramér's coefficient matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892799/using-pandas-calculate-cram%C3%A9rs-coefficient-matrix)

but when I put it into Python the definition doesn't end at the return:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> def cramers_corrected_stat(confusion_matrix):
...     # calculate Cramers V statistic for categorial-categorial association.
...     # uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher,
...     # Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
...
...     chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
...     n = confusion_matrix.sum()
...     phi2 = chi2/n
...     r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
...     phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))
...     rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
...     kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
...     return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))
...
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Hit Enter again.

Comment: If you're writing large functions it's probably easier to just write a script.

Comment: (In a normal interactive environment, Python would have stopped after the first blank line and thrown a SyntaxError. Either you've inadvertently altered the transcript you're showing us, or you're using some other weird environment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in REPL, you need two consecutive blank lines to finish the statement. However writing code in REPL is quite cumbersome, as you can't easily edit/fix previously written code, so I'd suggest you to save anything you do into `.py` file, where you can edit the code more easily and then run the code via `python ./myfile.py`.

Comment: One blank line is enough.

Comment: (Or at least should be - I agree with user2357112 supports Monica's suspicion that the OP didn't report correctly)